# How can I track the number of API calls I make to the Facebook Ads Insights API when using the Python SDK?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-python-business-sdk

I'm running into rate limiting issues when I try to pull data from the Facebook Ads Insights API. I'd like to track the number of calls I'm making, but I don't see how I can do that with the Python SDK.

I'll make what seems like one "call" on my end, but due to pagination, Facebook counts these requests as more than one call. Since the SDK handles the pagination I'm not sure how to track calls individually. Ideally I'd like to use the SDK rather than build from scratch to count each call.

Comment: I'm just gonna wait till the app approval flow tells me i havent made 1500 calls yet...